# How do you use SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject in ShellExtInit::Initialize?

Tags: windows, winapi

Docs tell me that [`SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-shcreateshellitemarrayfromdataobject) might be a simpler way to get a list of files from `DataObject` than `DataObject::GetFiles`. I want to use the function in `ShellExtInit::Initialize`, but cannot figure out how.

I need some kind of `IShellItemArray` to place the result in, but it is an abstract class so I don't know how to define it. And `SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject` final argument is supposed to be type `void**`, which I don't know how to satisfy.

How could I fix the code?

```
HRESULT MyContextMenuHandler::Initialize(PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidlFolder, IDataObject* pdtObj, HKEY hkeyProgId)
{
    [...]
    IShellItemArray items; // Class IShellItemArray is abstract
    HRESULT hr = SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject(pdtObj, IID_IShellItemArray, &items); // Cannot convert to void**
```

Comment: IshellitemArray is not abstract, its interface, so you need interface implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces must be accessed by pointers/references only. In this case, you need a pointer variable, and must pass the address of that variable to `SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject()` (using a type cast) so it can set that pointer to the address of an `IShellItemArray`-implementing object that the Shell creates for you. For example:

```
HRESULT MyContextMenuHandler::Initialize(PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidlFolder, IDataObject* pdtObj, HKEY hkeyProgId)
{
    ...
    IShellItemArray *items; // <-- pointer
    HRESULT hr = SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject(pdtObj, IID_IShellItemArray, (void**)&items); // <-- type cast
    ... 
}
```